# KafkaItemReader stops abruptly without seeking till the end offset

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-batch, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using spring batch and trying to dump all events from a Kafka Topic into txt file. We have 10 partitions for the topic. I have configured my KafkaItemReader to read from all 10 partitions.
This is a compact topic.

The poll timeout for the consumer is set to 5 mins.

This is my consumer config.

```
fetch.max.bytes = 10000000
fetch.max.wait.ms = 120000
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = XXXX
group.instance.id = XXXX
heartbeat.interval.ms = 30000
interceptor.classes = []
internal.leave.group.on.close = true
internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
isolation.level = read_uncommitted
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer max.partition.fetch.bytes = 2000000
max.poll.interval.ms = 600000
max.poll.records = 50
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor] receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 420000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 120000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
```

Message size is about 1kB per message.

My consumer runs and reaches about 70 percent of the offset and the job exits without showing any errors. the job status is COMPLETED but still we can see the lag count in the cluster for this consumer.

Sometimes I see messages like "Request to join the group since consumer pro-actively leaving the group" and  "Resetting the join group since consumer pro-actively leaving the group ".

I don't see any errors even after running it on DEBUG mode.

Am I missing out on any config?  Any help would be much appreciated.

I have reduced the max poll records size and also increased the max poll interval, and tried increasing other timeouts as well, but the result is always the same.